# Random points spread like old TV static in a polygon OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics

OpenGL version 3.1

Have to draw around 10000 randomly placed and colored points inside a rectangle to appear like old TV static but colored as shown in the image below.

[image: This is how my output should be]

Right now the code draws a solid fill even with plotting one point inside the rectangle.

```
void Question1(int width, int height, int gap)
   {
   //    SCREEN_WIDTH   = width;
   //    SCREEN_HEIGHT  = height;
   srand (time(NULL));

   //    float r = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
   //    float g = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
   //    float b = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);

   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);{
      glVertex2f(0 + gap, 0 + gap);
      glVertex2f(width - gap, 0 + gap);
      glVertex2f(width - gap, height - gap);
      glVertex2f(0 + gap, height - gap);
   }
   glEnd();
   glPointSize(1.0f);
   glBegin(GL_POINT);{
      for (int i=0; i < 1; i++){
        glColor3f(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0), rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0), rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        glVertex2i(rand(), rand());
    }
}
glFlush();
glEnd();
}
```

How do I fix my current code? Also, please give feedback on bad practices used in my code.

My output is currently a solid fill inside my rectangle with random color change.

[image]

Comment: I would have used a simple quad, perhaps marked with some custom attribute, and then use a fragment shader - in GLSL - to create the noise effect. Sure, you do not have random in GLSL, but you can write a congruential pseudorandom number generator if you know what you are doing. From my perspective `glBegin` and `glEnd` are a bad practice. Seek courses that avoid legacy immediate mode. However, if you *have* to use randomly placed color points (which appears to be the case), then my advice does not help you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes as @kromster pointed. I am not going to go on other mistakes, rather i'll tell you what is the best way I think.

In order to make it work, you have to do basically these things

1) set the `gap` to something

2) begin drawing the rectangle using `GL_LINE_LOOP`(just because, it would be easy with that)

3) then you just need 2 loops, one draws towards x-axis and other draws towards y-axis

that's it you're done. And this is how you would implement it.

```
//Gap is the distance from the sides
int gap = 100;

// Rectangle
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    //glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    //leftmost
    glVertex2d(SCREEN_WIDTH - (SCREEN_WIDTH-gap), SCREEN_HEIGHT - (SCREEN_HEIGHT-gap));
    //top
    glVertex2d(SCREEN_WIDTH-gap, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (SCREEN_HEIGHT-gap));
    //rightmost
    glVertex2d(SCREEN_WIDTH-gap, SCREEN_HEIGHT - gap);
    //bottom
    glVertex2d(SCREEN_WIDTH - (SCREEN_WIDTH-gap), SCREEN_HEIGHT - gap);
glEnd();

// drawing circles
glPointSize(4);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
     //random colors

    //points inside the rectangle
    for(int i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT - (2*gap); i++){     // Y-axis

        for(int j=0; j< SCREEN_WIDTH - (2*gap); j++ ){   // X-axis
                glColor3ub(rand()%255 + 1, rand()%255 + 1, rand()%255 + 1);
                glVertex2d((SCREEN_WIDTH - (SCREEN_WIDTH-gap)) + j, ((SCREEN_HEIGHT-(SCREEN_HEIGHT - gap)) + i));
        }
    }
    //glVertex2d(20, 50);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks I got it now. Couldn't break it down.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is a number of mistakes:

1. The error in `glVertex2i(rand(), rand())` - typical `rand()` returns a single number within `0.0..1.0` range. When you pass it to a function taking `i` (integers) they are way off and don't show up on the screen.

   Use the `glVertex2i(Round(gap + rand() * width), Round(gap + rand() * height))` or `glVertex2f(gap + rand() * width, gap + rand() * height)`
2. The `for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)` loop looks odd to - you do draw only one point?
3. `glBegin(GL_POINT);` is wrong too. Look up the correct constant name ;-)
4. `glFlush(); glEnd();` are misplaced too.

Comment: First of all, does `Round` have something to do with type casting?

Comment: `round` should convert number from `float` to `int`, as `glVertex2i` specifically expects. I don't recall how it is called in C++ though. You have to look it up.

Comment: And secondly, I corrected `glVertex2f(gap + rand() * width, gap + rand() * height)`. Yes, I was testing my loop for one point to see if it is even drawing a single point.

Comment: Got it, I will check that out.

Comment: Corrected the code but still not working.

Comment: Full of mistakes :-(

Comment: Yes, and I take full responsibility, been lazy but I want to learn and finish it.